# Set foreign key value to defualt value on delete in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I have a little issue that has been bothering me, I get the excess of the whole foreign key ideal, owever , could there be any way to get Laravel forign key to a defualt value whenever the reference table is deleted.

One reason I ask this is say for instance say a category is deleted, and the category has alot of say products, when ever the category is deleted the whole product goes along with it.

And then the use has to a new category and then recreate the product that was deleted.

Comment: Send your migration file code

Comment: i only need recommendation on solving this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set null on delete:

```
$table->...->onDelete('set null');
```

First make sure you set the foreign key field as nullable:

```
$table->integer('foreign_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```